# table update w/ cursor geometry conflict

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geometry, table, cursor

I'm creating a table using arcpy with a list of results (stored in 2d lists) following an update to some features. This can sometimes include geometry, so I've attempted to substitute those for a basic string to avoid any conflicts - all fields are TEXT. Still, I get this error - 
File "I:\IPP Geomatics Standards\Toolbox\Staging\Scripts\update_attributes.py", line 93, in resultsTable
    cursor.insertRow([z if z is not u[index] else 'Geom' for z in u], "update")
RuntimeError: table has no geometry

The 'index' variable is the known index in the list containing a geometry. This is the offending part of the function -

```
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(tablews + "\\results", nfields)
    for u in updatel:
        cursor.insertRow([z if z is not u[index] else 'Geom' for z in u], "update")
```

This should be omitting geometry altogether, but still gets flagged.

I suspect my insert statement is incorrect. As per ESRI documentation, one can insert multiple entries (i.e. one for each field) like so -

```
cursor.insertRow((x, y, z))
```

In this case, "u" is a list, and I'm trying to split it into separate entries, to the same end. The cursor must be interpreting the array as one entry, in the first field.

Answer (score 1):

Tuple of values to cursor.InsertRow must be complete. If SHAPE@ in nfields, it has to be defined somehow. Period. You might consider creating null geometry

Comment: All fields are string. When I add that field in particular with the right parameters, it converts to "SHAPE_" in name and behaves like a TEXT field would, so I'm unsure where the confusion lies. I can rename the SHAPE@ field as well but I'm convinced that looping over geometry is what's causing the issue.

Comment: I'm just going to scrap this and write to a csv instead, then maybe create a table from that.

Comment: It's possible the issue was with the comma in the insert statement. The new line for csv is as follows - writer.writerow([z if z is not u[index] else 'Geom' for z in u] + ["update"])